# Google App Script Change Background Color using Color Picker from menu item selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to implement a menu item that when selected will pop up the color picker and then change the background color of certain cells on the sheet to the color that was selected.

I have successfully been able to accomplish all of these things in my script but I do not have a good way for the user to easily pass a color that I can use to change the background. (I want to avoid having them required to change a certain cell to the color they want and then click the menu item to change the rest of the sheet)

Here is my current code:

```
//Function to create menu item
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sheet Options')
      .addItem('Change Background Color', 'colorMe')
      .addToUi();
}  

function colorMe(){
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

   // Code to get color value selected by user from ui color picker 
   // Replace #000000 with that value

   spreadsheet.getRangeList(['A:A', '1:1', 'H:H', 'I:I', 'N:U', 'B8:G9', 'E10:E31', 'F14:G31', 'B32:G100', '101:142']).activate()
   .setBackground('#000000');  

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike sorry I did not include that in the original question

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script and situation, how about selecting the color with the color picker on a dialog and sidebar? In this case, you can use javascript. How about this?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do but I have not been able to find an example of how to use the color picker in a dialog. I am not too familiar with sidebars but I am looking into that now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You can see the sample scripts at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs). If you have any questions, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Yes I have read through most of that page and I am still not sure how to use a color picker in those examples. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to implement a color picker? I want a good UI that can be used by someone who has limited technical experience and that is user friendly so they do not need to make a lot of clicks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As a sample script, I proposed a simple script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 5):

- You want to change the background color of cells on Spreadsheet.

  - The ranges are `'A:A', '1:1', 'H:H', 'I:I', 'N:U', 'B8:G9', 'E10:E31', 'F14:G31', 'B32:G100', '101:142'`.
- You want to select the color by a color picker.
- You can use a dialog and sidebar.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this answer, `<input>` elements with type color is used. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Sample script:

#### HTML: index.html

Please copy and paste the following script to the HTML of the script editor.

```
<input type="color" id="color" value="#ffffff">
<script>
document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  google.script.run.colorMe(this.value);
});
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script: code.gs

Please copy and paste the following script to the script of the script editor.

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
}

function colorMe(color) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet
  .getRangeList(['A:A', '1:1', 'H:H', 'I:I', 'N:U', 'B8:G9', 'E10:E31', 'F14:G31', 'B32:G100', '101:142'])
  .activate()
  .setBackground(color);
}
```

- When you run the function of `openDialog()`, a dialog is opened to the active Spreadsheet. And, when you click the color picker and select the color and click "OK", the color code is retrieved and `colorMe` is run. Then, the background color of cells are changed to the selected color.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

### References:

- [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)
- [`<input type="color">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)
- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the following article which helped me to implement a solution https://yagisanatode.com/2019/08/07/google-apps-script-google-standard-color-palette-picker-for-sidebar-and-dialog-boxes-in-google-sheets-google-docs-and-google-slides/